# How to Handle Automatically Generated DAG Run ID in the URL of Airflow REST API?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

I'm on Airflow v2.2.5 and am trying to use [this API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_xcom_entry) to fetch an xcom value.

My DAG runs are all done through the UI (scheduled/manual), and they have `dag_run_id`s with the format of `<manual/scheduled>__YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+00:00`.

Given that this `dag_run_id` appears in the REST API URL (`dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{dag_run_id}/taskInstances/{task_id}/xcomEntries/{xcom_key}`), I've tried various approaches to make the API work i.e. using a URL encoded string of the `dag_run_id`, using the string value directly, using the `execution_date`.

However, they all return 404 not found.

How can I format the `dag_run_id` properly to be used in the REST API URL?

EDIT: sharing my python script for calling the API:

```
import requests
import urllib

api_base_url = 'http://myairflow:8080/api/v1'
auth = ('username', 'password')


dag_id = 'mydag'

dag_runs_resp = requests.get(
    f'{api_base_url}/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns', 
    auth=auth
)
last_dag_run_id = dag_runs_resp.json()['dag_runs'][-1]['dag_run_id']

encoded_dag_run_id = urllib.parse.quote_plus(last_dag_run_id)

dag_run_resp = requests.get(
    f'{api_base_url}/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{encoded_dag_run_id}', 
    auth=auth
).json()

print(xcom_resp)
## {'detail': "DAGRun with DAG ID: 'mydag' and ## DagRun ID: 'manual__2023-06-13T02:15:02%2B00:00' not found",
##  'status': 404,
##  'title': 'DAGRun not found',
##  'type': 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/NotFound'}
```

Not sure why but the "+" or "%2B" symbol is not properly processed by the API, who doesn't convert it back to "+" when reading it as a dag_run_id.

From the last output, it seems that the `dag_run_id` is read as `manual__2023-06-13T02:15:02%2B00:00` instead of `manual__2023-06-13T02:15:02+00:00`

Comment: Could you add your python code for calling the API in the text? We might be able to help with something you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the url (you can full encode or just the run_id)

if you are using python when calling the api, here a code example that just encode the run_id and then add it to the full url (you can also see it in the browser address bar when you navigate into dag_run that the run_id is encoded)

```
import urllib.parse

run_id = "manual__2023-06-13T12:01:01+00:00"
encoded_run_id = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
print(encoded_run_id). # manual__2023-06-13T12%3A01%3A01%2B00%3A00
```

also, you can open the airflow swagger and see example :
[image]

Comment: I tried to do this, but airflow API is not picking up %2B as "+" symbol properly. I got the error message: DAGRun with DAG ID: 'mydag' and ## DagRun ID: 'manual__2023-06-13T02:15:02%2B00:00' not found

Comment: try to run it on the airflow swagger (added example to my answer), see if there is a difference in the encoding (haven't found in my example)